# JSON parsing in windows phone returns an exception

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, json.net

I am doing a sample for Json parsing in windows phone. I am using Json.Net ([json.codeplex.com/releases/view/78509](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/78509)) library, for parsing the response string. But am getting an exception while parsing. The exception is " Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'System.String". I am posting my code below.

**JSON Response I am getting**

> [{"runtime": ["194 min"], "rating": 7.6, "genres": ["Drama", "Romance"], "rated": "PG_13", "language": ["English", "French", "German", "Swedish", "Italian", "Russian"], "title": "Titanic", "filming_locations": "Santa Clarita, California, USA", "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjExNzM0NDM0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkxOTUwNw@@._V1._SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg", "imdb_url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/", "writers": ["James Cameron"], "imdb_id": "tt0120338", "directors": ["James Cameron"], "rating_count": 426376, "actors": ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Billy Zane", "Kathy Bates", "Frances Fisher", "Gloria Stuart", "Bill Paxton", "Bernard Hill", "David Warner", "Victor Garber", "Jonathan Hyde", "Suzy Amis", "Lewis Abernathy", "Nicholas Cascone", "Anatoly M. Sagalevitch"], "plot_simple": "A seventeen-year-old aristocrat, expecting to be married to a rich claimant by her mother, falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.", "year": 1997, "country": ["USA"], "type": "M", "release_date": 19980403, "also_known_as": ["Titanic in 3D"]}]

**And the parsing code is**

```
private void ParseResult(string input)
{
   var root =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject1[]>(input);// here getting the exception "Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'System.String"
}
```

**object class is**

```
 public class RootObject1
{
    public string runtime { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
    public string rated { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string poster { get; set; }
    public string imdb_url { get; set; }
    public string writers { get; set; }
    public string imdb_id { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your object does not correspond to the input.
"runtime" and "writers" fields are arrays of strings and rating is not an integer value, so the correct object must be something like:

```
    public class RootObject1
    {
        public string[] runtime { get; set; }
        public float rating { get; set; }
        public string rated { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string poster { get; set; }
        public string imdb_url { get; set; }
        public string[] writers { get; set; }
        public string imdb_id { get; set; }
    }
```